# Why don't external monitors have keyboard brightness controls?

Tags: display, keyboard-shortcuts

I'm about to replace my Apple Cinema Display, which was fantastic for several reasons, but one of them was that you could adjust the brightness with the keyboard instead of an on-screen display. Even Windows and Linux could talk to it with third-party software.

It's frustrating finding out that ~zero new monitors allow for keyboard brightness adjustment. Is there a reason for this, especially since most new monitors have at least a USB hub or connect over USB-C?

Comment: The USB hub on the monitor is cheap, easy to make, and has nothing to do with the monitor it is attached to.  An external interface from a computer to control monitor settings is none of these things.  I would bet that the ROI for monitor manufacturers just wasn't there.. otherwise.. they would still exist.

Comment: Most new monitors have a software to control the monitor from Windows or Mac though? And they usually allow for keyboard shortcuts. ex. LG OnScreen Control - version 4.70

Comment: In order for a screen to support brightness control, it needs to have a backlight. Not every technology uses a backlight, and a backlight brings both pro's and cons to the table. Manufacturers often find the cons outweight the pro's, such as bad dimming zones, slow refreshrates, and costs.

Comment: @LPchip  Only OLED doesn't use backlighting. Which is like not even 1% of the market share right now. All LCD monitors use backlighting.